# Seamlessly transition back and forth with only one animation class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use one class to trigger an animation, and upon removal of that class redo that animation in reverse.

It's hard to visualize, so I've created a [CodePen of where I'm at currently.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJWrag)

You'll notice that when `.zoom` is removed from `#box`, the `#box` just vanishes. It doesn't do the animation in reverse, which is ultimately the goal.

How can I seamlessly transition back and forth, with only one animation class? Normally I might use transitions, but you can't transition with transforms.

Comment: is `$` an alias for jQuery in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `.zoomout` `class` , `css` animations , utilizing `.removeClass()` , second `class` at `.toggleClass()`

```js
window.onclick = function() {
  if (!$("#box").is(".zoom")) {
    $("#box").removeClass("zoomout")
      .toggleClass("zoom");
  } else {
    $("#box").toggleClass("zoom zoomout");
  }
};
```

```css
#box {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
  margin: 16px 0px;
}
.zoom {
  animation: zoom 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation: zoom 500ms;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation: zoom 500ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.zoomout {
  animation: zoomout 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation: zoomout 500ms;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation: zoomout 500ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes zoomout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="box"></div>
Click the document to toggle the box.
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOxxKE

Comment: Thanks, but there seems to be an awkward twitch at the end of the animation.

Comment: @Elegant.Scripting Can describe _"awkward twitch"_ ?

Comment: I fixed it. When you created the new zoomout animation, you switched the opacity, but forgot to switch the scale. Thanks a bunch though, this is a good solution!